# A problem on degree of freeedom?

Tags: thermodynamics, classical-mechanics, degrees-of-freedom

> [The problem is roughly]
>         **Toy “Supermag” makes it possible to construct, among others, polyhedrons — e.g. tetrahedrons, cubes, and many irregular polyhedrons, where the edges
>   of the polyhedron are made of magnetic bars, which are connected at the vertices with the help of steel balls. The steel balls
>   fix the endpoint of a steel bar to itself firmly, but the angle
>   between magnetic bars meeting at a steel ball can be changed
>   with a little effort. It appears that a tetrahedron is a rigid
>   construction, but a cube can be easily deformed. Prove the
>   following theorem: a convex polyhedron is rigid then and only
>   then if all the faces of the polyhedron are triangle?**

In the problem source hint was somewhat by use of Euler formula on polyhedron and concept of degree of freedom.

How to solve the problem ?

Comment: any sort of way of approach to the problem may help

Comment: the converse statement find solution if it can be proved that degree of freedom exceed 6 in such a case